# Backslash not getting formatted with addslashes function + php

Tags: php, mysql

I am having following php string: "Device/ mo\bile's";
I want to insert it into db and so before insert i am sanitizing it with addslashes function
and sanitization happens but the string is inserted into the db as "Device/ mobile's" ie. backlash vanishes.

I want to retain '\' also.
Anybody suggest how can i do that.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the string is "Device/ mobile's", why do you want to insert anything else into the database? Please go read [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/).

Comment: Whenever `addslashes` touches SQL a bug is born. There are other functions suitable for this. Give us an example of what you are doing (and why is that `phpmyadmin` tag there?)

Comment: If you want to retain the escaping slash: `addslashes(addslashes($str))`. ***BUT*** that means you're doing it completely wrong.

Comment: "Device/ mo\bile's" is stored as "Device/ mobile's"

Comment: Can anybody tell me why i got two down votes because i understand i did one mistake of tagging phpmyadmin and removed it as soon as i realised. Apart from that,deceze's answer helped me, so i accepted his answer also. Please advise me where was i wrong so that it can help me in future. I will appreciate if at-least one down vote is removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `addslashes` for escaping SQL. In fact, don't use `addslashes` for anything. If you are still using the by now deprecated mysql_* functions, use `mysql_real_escape_string`. If you're using the newer mysqli_* or PDO extension, use prepared statements. Then all data will be inserted properly. If you use unrelated escaping functions which do not consider to appropriate escaping rules for the language at hand, you won't get the correct results.